# What is the round seat that often belongs to a sofa set called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the picture. There is a round blue seat that belongs to a sofa set. People can sit on the sofa while putting their legs on it for relaxation.

Sometimes, we can see them in the lounge of a bank or a cinema or in waiting rooms in general like in this picture
[image]

**Note:** It may or may not have legs, it it does, then the legs should be very short.

**What is the round seat that often belongs to a sofa set called?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In British English it is traditionally called a *pouffe*.

I think that some people avoid that word now, and call it a *footstool*.

Comment: what about hassock? the same thing?> "https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hassock"

Comment: @Tom: apparently so, to Americans. To me a hassock is only the cushion used in church.

Comment: @Colin Fine - "I think that some people avoid that word now, and call it a footstool.". Because 'pouffe' (a cushion) is pronounced very much like 'poof', a British hate-speech term for a gay male?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: indeed. It's hard to use the word without getting a laugh.

Answer (score 1):

**Ottoman**, the padded, low-lying upholstered chair, got its name from the Ottoman Empire that ruled Turkey in the 1700s.

[Ref](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1GCEU_en-GBIN822IN822&sxsrf=ACYBGNSywMwmZ-dST-5apI4QQ_frzgq_dQ:1578473964934&q=ottoman%20chair&tbm=isch&chips=q:ottoman%20chair,g_1:round:P1oUQ07_Rwo%3D&usg=AI4_-kTaki2sAe02cZqtwlmxs2tTW1l07w&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjaht7f0fPmAhW1yTgGHZZgBGsQgIoDKAB6BAgKEAQ&biw=1536&bih=792https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1GCEU_en-GBIN822IN822&sxsrf=ACYBGNSywMwmZ-dST-5apI4QQ_frzgq_dQ:1578473964934&q=ottoman%20chair&tbm=isch&chips=q:ottoman%20chair,g_1:round:P1oUQ07_Rwo%3D&usg=AI4_-kTaki2sAe02cZqtwlmxs2tTW1l07w&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjaht7f0fPmAhW1yTgGHZZgBGsQgIoDKAB6BAgKEAQ&biw=1536&bih=792).

Comment: In Australian English we would also use “footstool” and “pouf” (old-fashioned), but ottoman is common too. 

https://www.target.com/c/stools-poufs-accent-furniture-living-room/-/N-56d55?Nao=0

Comment: If you referred to an Ottoman in respect of that picture, I would not think of the round thing at all: I would suppose you meant one of the couches (though I would not call them Ottomans either). British English speaker.

Comment: To a Brit, an ottoman is a blanket box that goes at the foot of the bed.